# Override method with subclass as argument

Tags: java, design, object-oriented-design

When you want an overrided method to take as argument a subclass of the argument of the overridden method, you usualy accomplish that with generics (as discussed in [Template pattern with varying input type in overridden method](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/267037/template-pattern-with-varying-input-type-in-overridden-method)). An example of that can be seen in my `methodA` of the class `Parent` and `Child`

I am wondering if it is possible to do the same thing with a method that takes as argument an object of the class itself (my `methodB`)

```
abstract class Super {}

class Sub extends Super {}

abstract class Parent<S extends Super> {
    abstract void methodA(S argument);
    abstract void methodB(Parent<S> parent);
}

public class Child extends Parent<Sub> {
    @Override
    void methodA(Sub argument) {}

    @Override
    void methodB(Child child) {}
}
```

In the code above `methodB` in `Child` does not override `methodB` from `Parent`.

I could of course use casting in `methodB` from `Child` as in:

```
public class Child extends Parent<Sub> {
    @Override
    void methodB(Parent<Sub> child) {
        (Child) child
    }
}
```

But as a general rule I try to avoid casting as much as possible.

Is it possible to have an overrided `methodB` in `Child` (with signature `@Override void methodB(Child child)`)? If so, what would the signature of `methodB` (in `Parent`) look like?

Comment: This question already has [an answer on Stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14665499/java-generics-interface-method-that-receives-type-argument-of-implementing-clas).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's assume what you want was possible. Let's make another child class:

```
public class Child2 extends Parent<Sub> {
    @Override
    void methodA(Sub argument) {}

    @Override
    void methodB(Child2 child) {}
}
```

Now, what if I have this:

```
Parent<Sub> child = new Child();
Parent<Sub> child2 = new Child2();
child.methodB(child2);
```

The `child` is a pointer of type `Parent<Sub>`, so it's `methodB` is expecting an argument of type `Parent<Sub>` - which is OK because `child2` is also a pointer of type `Parent<Sub>`. But the object `child` refers to is of type `Child`, which it's `methodB` only accepts argument of type `Child` - and `child2` is pointing to an object of type `Child2` - which is not a subclass of `Child`...